# Delaying pods creation or recreating pods until tasks in other pods are completed

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I need some help with better kubernetes resource deployment.

Essentially, I've 2 components. C1 and C2.

My task is to not deploy C2 pods or any resources until the tasks which are running in C1 are finished.

C1 will install some dars into server machine. --> this will take almost an hour to finish
C2 is dependent on a dar that c1 will install.

We have a single helm in which all resources are defined.
As soon as we install that chart. It will deploy every resources(pods, services, stateful state) in parallel.
C1 pods will come up, c2 pods will also come up.
But when you check container logs. C2 containers will have lots of error saying not found class or resources.

I am looking for a way by which I will be able to wait, until all dars are deployed through c1. If not wait then atleast, keep destroying and recreating until all dars are installed.

Comment: Could you explain what a “dar” is in this context? It doesn't seem to be a widely used term and might be specific to your company.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes does not model such dependencies between resources. All your pods should be loosely coupled. A pod that has unmet dependencies might not report as ready or healthy, but is running just fine. If written correctly, the pod will eventually discover the dependencies as they become available. Yes, this produces tons of error logs. But that isn't necessarily a *problem*.

Whereas the Kubernetes/Helm configuration describes a target state for your deployments, you want to vary this state over time. Thus, you likely want to perform *separate* deployments/configurations for components C1 and C2. Using some tool outside of Kubernetes/Helm, you first want to apply the configuration for C1 and wait until those jobs have finished, then apply the C2 configuration. This could be as simple as a shell script that regularly polls for the status of C1.

That you have such a long-running setup task could also indicate that your current software architecture is not well suited for Kubernetes- or container-based management. Statefulness isn't a problem (when externalized appropriately), but such extremely slow deployments could be a symptom of deeper conceptual issues. For example, it might be sufficient if C1 is idempotent so that the slow initialization is only performed once in each Kubernetes cluster, and that the C1 initialization overhead is negligible for later deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two separate pods you might want to use the C1 container as an [init Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) for a pod which has container C2 as the app container.

> Init containers can contain utilities or setup scripts not present in an app image.
> A Pod can have multiple containers running apps within it, but it can also have one or more init containers, which are run before the app containers are started.
>
> - Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:
> - Init containers always run to completion.
>   Each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.

Thus C2 will not start unless C1 has run to completion.